# Html.ValidationSummary: Make two different messages for one property depending on some values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

here's my question.

I have a ViewModel with some string property. I have a client validation for that property and what's more this client validation has two messages depending on some other boolean property. But also I have a Html.ValidationSummary on my View and here I have the issue: This ValidationSummary shows always only one message (that I have in ErrorMessage in my Required attribute). And as a result I've faced the problem when my validation message has one string, but ValidationSummary shows another.

My ViewModel:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Unique Facility Member ID Required")]
    [Remote("ValidateFacilityMemberID", "Members", AdditionalFields = "MemberID,FacilityID")]
    public string MemberFacilityEnrollmentsFacilityMemberID { get; set; }
```

My Controller where I try to change the ModelState error (it works):

```
private void ChangeModelStateErrorForKeyfobProperty()
    {
        string facilityMemberIdString = "Unique Facility Member ID";
        string keyfobRequired = "* Keyfob Required";
        string memberFacilityEnrollmentsFacilityMemberID = "MemberFacilityEnrollmentsFacilityMemberID";

        if (ViewBag.CurrentFacility.IsAF)
        {
            List<string> errors = ModelState.Values
                .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();

            foreach (var error in errors)
            {
                if (error.Contains(facilityMemberIdString))
                {
                    ModelState.Remove(memberFacilityEnrollmentsFacilityMemberID);
                    ModelState.AddModelError(memberFacilityEnrollmentsFacilityMemberID, keyfobRequired);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
@model EditMemberViewData
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit " + Model.FullName();
    var CurrentFacility = ViewBag.CurrentFacility as Facility;
    var FacilityMemberIDLabel = (ViewBag.CurrentFacility.IsAF) ? "Keyfob #" : "Unique Facility Member ID #";
    var FacilityMemberIDValidationMessage = (ViewBag.CurrentFacility.IsAF) ? "* Keyfob Required" : "* Unique Facility Member ID Required";
}
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Members", new { id = CurrentFacility.FacilityIDNumber, memid = Model.MemberId }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary();
                        <td><label for="FacilityMemberID">@FacilityMemberIDLabel</label> </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MemberFacilityEnrollmentsFacilityMemberID, new {style = "margin-left: 9px;"})
                            <br/>
                            @Html.ValidationMessage("MemberFacilityEnrollmentsFacilityMemberID", FacilityMemberIDValidationMessage)
                            <span id="MemberFacilityIdValidWarning" style="display: none; color: red;"></span>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
```

So could you please help me? How can I teach ValidationSummary to show different messages depending on some situations?

Comment: Post your relevant code please

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with that?